# What is the probability of 5 anomalies appearing in a batch of 100, from a data set of 1000 examples and 10 anomalies?

Tags: probability, combinatorics, hypergeometric-distribution

I am trying to work out the expected value of the following example:

A data set contains 1000 examples in total. 10 examples can be considered anomalous.

I am randomly drawing 100 examples to form a batch.

I have two related questions.

1)  What is the probability that a batch will contain 5 or more anomalies?

2) What is the probability that a batch will contain 1 or more anomalies?

**Attempted Solution**

I believe I need to calculate the combinations.

I can start by considering the probability that I draw no anomalies and taking the compliment. Let $X$ be the number of anomalies.

$P(X \ge 1 ) = 1 - P(X = 0)$, where $P(X = 0) = C(10,0) C(990,100) / C(1000,100)  = 0.346 $
so  $P(X \ge 1 ) = 0.653$

So 65.3% of the time a batch will contain at least one anomaly? I'm doubting myself because that seems so high.

For the probability of drawing at least 5 anomalies, I'm less sure where to begin.

Comment: Aren't you in the process of studying Binomial distributions?  If so, then most likely your batches are samples *with replacement.*  If not, then see our posts about *hypergeometric* distributions.

Comment: There is no replacement in this context. The idea is you are drawing 100 from 1000 all at once.

Comment: Then generalize your formula about combinations: it is correct.  Note that the answer to (1) is the sum $P(X=5)+\cdots + P(X=10).$

Comment: The comment thread below was deleted, so for completion, I will post the [solution](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=1-%28Binomial%5B10%2C0%5D*Binomial%5B990%2C100%5D+%2BBinomial%5B10%2C1%5D*Binomial%5B990%2C99%5D+%2BBinomial%5B10%2C2%5D*Binomial%5B990%2C98%5D%2BBinomial%5B10%2C3%5D*Binomial%5B990%2C97%5D+%2BBinomial%5B10%2C4%5D*Binomial%5B990%2C96%5D+++%29%2F+Binomial%5B1000%2C100%5D) The probability of drawing 5 anomalies is ~ 0.15%